# Yii : strange errors when using Cjuidialog

Tags: php, yii

Yii 1.1.14
I'm creating an application, I want to get a popup to select a year and then generate a reporting file corresponding to this selected year.
To test things before I had a fixed variable for the year and it worked fine.

Now I tried to use CJuiDialog to ask for the year.

Here's the controller action :

```
    public function actionReporting()
    {
            $years = array();
            $yearstmp = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("SELECT DISTINCT year FROM {{planning}} ORDER BY year")->queryAll();
            foreach ($yearstmp as $yeartmp) {
                    $years[$yeartmp['year']] = $yeartmp['year'];
                    $lastyear = $yeartmp['year'];
            }

            if(isset($_POST['run'])) {
                    $this->actionXlsabsences($years[$_POST['year']]);
            } else {
                    $this->render(
                            'reporting',
                            array(
                                    'years'=>$years,
                                    'lastyear'=>$lastyear
                    ));
            }
    }
```

And this is the view :

```
<div class="reportingtest">
    <?php 
        $this->widget('zii.widgets.CMenu', array(
                    'items'=>array(
                            array('label'=>Yii::t('app','app.menu.reporting.planning.xlsabsence'), 'url'=>array('/planning/xlsAbsences')),
                    ),
            ));
    ?>
</div>


<div class="reporting">
    <?php 
        $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog',array(
                    'id'=>'mydialog',
                    'options'=>array(
                            'title'=>Yii::t('app','reporting.xlsabsence'),
                            'autoOpen'=>false,
                    ),
            ));
    ?>
    <div class="well">
            <?php echo CHtml::beginForm('','post'); ?>
            <table class="contentheader">
                    <tr>
                            <th><?php echo Yii::t('app','reporting.select.year'); ?></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                            <td><?php echo CHtml::DropDownList('year', $lastyear, $years, array('options'=>array($lastyear=>array('selected'=>true)) )); ?></td>
                    </tr>
            </table>
            <br />
            <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Run', array('name' => 'run', 'class' => 'btn btn-success')); ?>
            <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
    </div>

    <?php 
            $this->endWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog');
            echo CHtml::link(Yii::t('app','app.menu.reporting.planning.xlsabsence'), '#', array(
                    'onclick'=>'$("#mydialog").dialog("open"); return false;',
            ));
    ?>
</div>
```

But this does not work :
The old link in div reportingtest does not work anymore (page not found at ......./index.php?r=planning/xlsAbsences).
But the action xlsAbsences exists and has not changed.
The new link in div reporting does not work better - same error.

And here's the most weird thing : 
If in the view, I delete the line :

```
<?php echo CHtml::DropDownList ....
```

=> the old link works again.

But perhaps this is normal but please I need to understand whats happening !?

EDIT :
I found in application log the following :

```
2014/02/04 21:26:02 [error] [php] Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php:2325)
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CBaseController.php(126): require()
#1 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CBaseController.php(95): PlanningController->renderInternal()
#2 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CController.php(869): PlanningController->renderFile()
#3 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CController.php(782): PlanningController->renderPartial()
#4 C:\wamp\www\yii02\yiiars02\protected\controllers\PlanningController.php(632): PlanningController->render()
#5 C:\wamp\www\yii02\yiiars02\protected\controllers\PlanningController.php(318): PlanningController->actionXlsAbsences()
#6 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\actions\CInlineAction.php(49): PlanningController->actionReporting()
#7 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CController.php(308): CInlineAction->runWithParams()
#8 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(133): PlanningController->runAction()
#9 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\filters\CFilter.php(40): CFilterChain->run()
#10 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CController.php(1145): CAccessControlFilter->filter()
#11 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\filters\CInlineFilter.php(58): PlanningController->filterAccessControl()
#12 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\filters\CFilterChain.php(130): CInlineFilter->filter()
#13 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CController.php(291): CFilterChain->run()
#14 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CController.php(265): PlanningController->runActionWithFilters()
#15 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(282): PlanningController->run()
#16 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\web\CWebApplication.php(141): CWebApplication->runController()
#17 C:\wamp\www\yii01\framework\base\CApplication.php(180): CWebApplication->processRequest()
#18 C:\wamp\www\yii02\yiiars02\index.php(13): CWebApplication->run()
REQUEST_URI=/yii02/yiiars02/index.php?r=planning/reporting
in C:\wamp\www\yii02\yiiars02\protected\views\planning\reporting.php (39)
in C:\wamp\www\yii02\yiiars02\protected\controllers\PlanningController.php (632)
in C:\wamp\www\yii02\yiiars02\protected\controllers\PlanningController.php (318)
```

I also have seen some errors in my code - I made the corrections and updated the source code posted above.

But the error is allways the same (and the log too) !

When I introduce a var_dump($listData) before line 2325 of CHtml.php I get :
array(2) { [2013]=> string(4) "2013" [2014]=> string(4) "2014" }

If I load the reporting page, add "var_dump($listData); exit;" before line 2325 of CHtml.php the process goes on without any error.

I do not understand what's wrong with that !?

---

### EDIT 2 :

I worked on this problem for a while now. 
If I do not make a call to another action of the same controler (as I tried to do actionReporting) all works fine.
I really need help here because I can't understand why this call of another action is a problem - I had a look on other posts and I had the impression that this is the way to do.
I also wonder why the error appears only on application.log but no standard yii error page appears.

Comment: Are there any javascript errors in the browser console?

Comment: check the IDs of dropdowns,maybe it's a matter of id conflicts

Comment: No javascript error - I already tried by changing id - same result

Answer (score 0):

I found my error - I had a bad render instruction in the called action - not easy to find